# Get Flash movie elapsed details from Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to determine how much of a Flash video has elapsed from Javascript code? This would be for videos that I have not created and have no control over, e.g. from Youtube, Vimeo, etc.

I don't need to control the video in any way, just need to see how far it has played and, if possible, total running time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit? Link to example? I don't know Flash at all. Thanks.

Comment: ExternalInterface is a native class to AS3 it allows you to make callback functions inside of the SWF that is accessible to JavaScript. There are a tons of examples for it on the web. But if you don't know flash then that might be an issue.

Comment: This is assuming you have the source files for the flash video player(SWF) and have an understanding of how to access the data you want in the player itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. But it will be dependent in part on which player you are using. If you are using an embeddable video player, instead of a custom player, the player will need to have a javascript method available to give this information.
In the case of YouTube, an API exists:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

But if you build your own player, that loads in another player, for example the chromeless YouTube player for Actionscript 3 - you can monitor the playback with the part of teh application you build, and make it avaiable via the ExternalInterface in actionscript.

The Actionscript ExternalInterface class is the preferred way to handle communication between flash objects and javascript.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks. Awesome username by the way.